# Project Euler 126: could someone explain?

Tags: geometry

[Project Euler 126](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=126) says: "If we then add a second layer to this solid it would require forty-six cubes to cover every visible face."

How come? I thought lay another 3x2x1 over a 3x2x1 makes it 3x2x2, and you need 6 to cover the top, 6 to cover the bottom, 3+2+3+2 to cover each layer, so the total is 32, every white color face is covered, right? How am I wrong here? I have thought hard, but I don't understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can ask this kind of questions at the Project Euler forum: http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewforum.php?f=50

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the intention is to cover the covered cuboid.

Comment: Bingo.  This is what it means.

Answer (score 1):

first you need 22 to cover the six sides. then you need to cover 3 different corners, which needs 3* 4 + 2*4 + 1*4 = 24. totally 46.